# Jenkins Cron Syntax - How to Perform a Half of Hour

Tags: jenkins, cron

The requirement for my pipeline schedule is from `09:00 pm` to `04:30 am` I wrote the schedule like this `triggers { cron('H H(21-4:30) * * *') }` but it did not work, so how to correct this?

Comment: cron('H H(21-23) * * *')
cron('H H(0-4) * * *')

Answer (score 0):

I think following cron will work for you.

```
H/30 21-23,0-4 * * *
```

At every 30th minute past every hour from 21 through 23 and every hour from 0 through 4.